# how to optimize mysql group by

Tags: mysql, sql

table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `l_not_200_page` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `server` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `domain` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `query_string` varchar(384) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_time_domain_status_page` (`time`,`domain`,`status`,`page`),
  KEY `page` (`page`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM  `l_not_200_page` 
WHERE TIME
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(  '2014-03-25' ) 
AND TIMESTAMP(  '2014-03-25 23:59:59' ) 
AND domain =1
AND STATUS = 404
GROUP BY PAGE

1
SIMPLE
l_not_200_page
range
idx_time_domain_status_page
idx_time_domain_status_page
7
NULL
1
Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

it's very slow, how to optimize ?

sql:
SELECT PAGE , COUNT( * ) AS cnt
FROM  `l_not_200_page` 
WHERE TIME
BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(  '2014-03-26 12:00:00' ) 
AND TIMESTAMP(  '2014-03-26 12:30:00' ) 
AND domain =1
AND STATUS = 499
GROUP BY PAGE ORDER BY cnt DESC 
LIMIT 100

the daily amount of data about 900w

Answer (score 1):

Change the index to:

```
create index `idx_domain_status_time_page` on  l_not_200_page(`domain`, `status`, `time`, `page`)
```

When MySQL uses an index for a `where` clause, the best index has all the fields in equality comparisons followed by one with an inequality, such as `between`.  With `time` as the first element, it doesn't use the index for `domain` and `status` (well, it uses an index scan instead of a direct lookup).

For further optimization, you can get rid of the `group by` by choosing one row per page:

```
SELECT lp.*  FROM  l_not_200_page lp WHERE TIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP(  '2014-03-25' ) AND TIMESTAMP(  '2014-03-25 23:59:59' ) AND
      domain = 1 AND STATUS = 404 AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from l_not_200_page lp2
                  where lp2.page = lp.page and
                        lp2.domain = 1 and lp2.status = 404 and
                        lp2.TIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2014-03-25) AND TIMESTAMP('2014-03-25 23:59:59') AND
                        lp2.id > lp.id
                 )
```

For this, an additional index on `(page, domain, status, time)` would help.